# Why did Ram free Ahilya from her bondage?

Tags: ramayana, rama

Ram freed Ahilya who was made stone by her husband Gautam Rishi.

I want to know why did he free her ?

What did he say on freeing her ?

Was Ahilya innocent ? Or She had got enough punishment ?

Comment: Related question - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/57808/why-was-ahilya-saved-by-rama-even-though-she-could-see-through-indras-disguise